# Pushing a variable value into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

**Problem**

I am trying to push a returning variables value into an array. This is my code, however I'm returning an empty array and am not sure what's wrong.

**JavaScript**

```
var my_arr = [];

function foo() {
  var unitValue = parseFloat($('#unitVal1').val());
  var percentFiner = parseFloat($('#percent1').val());
  var total = unitValue * 1000;

  return my_arr.push({
    unit: unitValue,
    percent: percentFiner
  });
}
```

Comment: it should be array of objects and can't see `micronConv` here.

Comment: Why so many upvotes? That code doesn't return an array. And did you check `my_arr`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
return my_arr.push({
        unit:   unitValue, 
        percent: percentFiner});
```

This isn't returning the new Array - this is returning the new length of the Array! Split these out:

```
my_arr.push({
        unit:   unitValue, 
        percent: percentFiner});

return my_arr;
```

Comment: or even `return my_arr.push(...) && my_arr;` would work too ;-)

Answer (score 9):

`Array.push` returns a length of the changed array, not the array itself

[See the Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)